# ng-grid editable some cells

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is there any way for make my ng-grid JUST SOME CELLS editable?

```
 $scope.gridOptionsReports = {
    data: 'Reports',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'Row', displayName: ' Row ', width: 40 },
        { field: 'OperationStatus', displayName: 'Operation', width: 120 },
        { field: 'Date', displayName: 'Date', width: 100 },
        { field: 'Consideration', displayName: 'Consideration', width: 80 },
        { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description', width: 400 }
    ]
};
```

I want to make my **Date** and **Description** field editable.But now all of my fields are editable.
Thanks.